# How to resolve No such column SQLiteException

Tags: android, sqlite

Let me come to the point directly.I am getting "No such column exception" even though the syntax of the query is right.
The below is the table creation.

```
    private void subCategory() {
    String query = ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SUB_CATEGORY + " (" 
            + COL_SUB_CATEGORY_ID + "  VARCHAR(50), "
            + COL_SUB_CATEGORY_NAME + " VARCHAR(250) , " 
            + COL_SUB_CATEGORY_REFRENCE_ID + " VARCHAR(250) , " 
            + COL_SUB_CATEGORY_IMAGE_PATH + "  VARCHAR(300), "
            + COL_SUB_CATEGORY_IMAGE_DATA + " BLOB , " 
            + COL_SUB_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION + " VARHCAR(250) );");
    database.execSQL(query);
}
```

And the place i am trying to get the values is .

```
            Cursor cursor1 = db.query(DbHandler.TABLE_SUB_CATEGORY, null, " COL_SUB_CATEGORY_REFRENCE_ID " + "= ?", new String[] { categoryId }, null, null, null);
```

and i am using one more type of call.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DbHandler.TABLE_SUB_CATEGORY + " WHERE COL_SUB_CATEGORY_REFRENCE_ID = ? ";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { categoryId })
```

Both the approach doesn't seem working. i am getting "no such column exception".

Can someone please help me resolving this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably added that column **after** the database was created upon a previous run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the create table query COL_SUB_CATEGORY_REFRENCE_ID is a constant but in the select query you have used "COL_SUB_CATEGORY_REFRENCE_ID".

Instead of :

```
            Cursor cursor1 = db.query(DbHandler.TABLE_SUB_CATEGORY, null, " COL_SUB_CATEGORY_REFRENCE_ID " + "= ?", new String[] { categoryId }, null, null, null);
```

Try:

```
            Cursor cursor1 = db.query(DbHandler.TABLE_SUB_CATEGORY, null, COL_SUB_CATEGORY_REFRENCE_ID + "= ?", new String[] { categoryId }, null, null, null);
```